# Install-on-Demand Wrapper Function for Executables

Tags: bash, shell, command, recursive, function

How do I make the following function work correctly

```
# Install git on demand
function git()
{
    if ! type git &> /dev/null; then sudo $APT install git; fi
    git $*;
}
```

by making `git $*` call `/usr/bin/git` instead of the function `git()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```shell
# Install git on demand
function git()
{
    if ! type -f git &> /dev/null; then sudo $APT install git; fi
    command git "$@";
}
```

The `command` built-in suppresses function lookup. I've also changed your `$*` to `"$@"` because that'll properly handle arguments that aren't one word (e.g., file names with spaces).

Further, I added the `-f` argument to `type`, because otherwise it'll notice the function.

You may want to consider what to do in case of error (e.g., when `apt-get install` fails).

Comment: Thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps a more generic function being able to run any command. In this case the '-f' can be replaced with '-t'. The collision with the function will not occur.

```
function runcmd()
{
  if ! type -t $1 >/dev/null; then
    pkg=$(apt-file search -x "bin.*$1\$" | cut -d: -f1)
    sudo apt-get install $pkg
  fi
  eval "$@"
}
```

Of course 'apt-get install' errors must be handled.

Comment: Good one. La Suède Deux Points ;) Thanks mate.